# Cycles, Mitsuba, Lux - Speed by Necessity - The Correct (non-subjective) Answer

Tags: rendering, luxrender-render-engine

I know stackexchange frowns on "suggest this software" questions that can be subjective, but I do believe there is a correct answer (non-subjective) to this question.

I have to render for speed and quality and can (for these particular projects) do without the excessive control that cycles offers.

I've seen Luxrender and this if I am not mistaken is much slower than cycles. Mitsuba might be faster, but I read it has some limitations.

Which of these renderers can give speed and quality even if some sacrifices must be made?

Comment: Just pick the one you know better ? the most knowledge you have about it the faster you will be setting up the renderings.
About "which software renders faster ?" I'm not sure there are any real differences, it depends from your hardware and you scene, and what you will be able to do with one you surely can do it with the other ray tracers too.

Comment: https://www.blenderguru.com/articles/render-engine-comparison-cycles-vs-giants/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an old adage from the industry:

“Time, Money, Quality; Pick Two”

The gist being that you can only have two points of that triangle, at a cost of the one you do not select.

It has held true long enough to become a trope.

Comment: I think this answer, simple though it is, really hits the mark. It doesn't specifically answer the question, but really it does quite well! Thank you very much.

Comment: Absolutely true.